# how to i make changes in appearance of react-native-element search bar

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-ios

[image]

In the image above half of the search box is cut off, how do i make the search box fit within the view. Search box is inside one view and the region below that where "Home Page is written is inside another view.

Also I don't want the big transparent border for the search box. How do I get rid of the transparent region?

```
<View style={styles.screenHeaderContainerBelow}>
            <SearchBar
                lightTheme
                containerStyle={{flex:1, height:undefined}}
                onChangeText={() => {}}
                placeholder='Type Here...' />
            </View>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the four examples from [the documentation for SearchBar](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/searchbar/), and got the bottom one's big transparent border to go away by adding the prop `inputStyle={{margin: 0}}` as well as `noIcon` to make the formatting look better:

```
<SearchBar
          lightTheme
          noIcon
          inputStyle={{margin: 0}}
          onChangeText={someMethod}
          placeholder='Type Here...' />
```

[image]

Try taking out `containerStyle={{flex:1, height:undefined}}` to see if that fixes the problem of half the search box being cut off.